# Specific Field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm importing data from `csv` file to my `MongoDB` with `mongoimport`. In one field I have a phone numbers which start with front `0` (zero) like: 0908566. My mongoimport deletes this zero from data on import. How could I avoid it?
I'm using this command

```sh
mongoimport --db Terema -c terema_data --type csv --host SOMEIP --port 27017 --username SOMEUSERNAME --password SOMEPASS --authenticationDatabase admin  --file terema.csv --headerline
```

Comment: I tried that, but I'm not getting that explanation there, when I try something like ` --headerline --columnsHaveType string()` it throws `syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: does I need explicitly write down all columns in `--fields` because it has a lot of cols..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223443/mongoimport-choosing-field-type does this help You?