# How to import a CSV file with a field having leading zero values into MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, mongodb-tools

MongoDB seems to have trouble importing data,
I tried to import csv file with values having leading zeros enclosed in double quotes but once imported the leading zeros gets removed.

Sample CSV File

```
duns_number,company_name,type,country,original_company_name,search_key,cik,last_scraped_date
"194946757","Carbonite, Inc.",Public,United States,,,"0001340127",
"116670284",SolarWinds Corp,Public,United States,SolarWinds Corporation,,"0001739942",
```

Sample Import Script

```
mongoimport --type csv -d ds_dnb -c ds_company_masterlist  --headerline --drop ""
```

Is there any other way of forcing it to just import the data as all text?

Comment: There is an option (parameter) called as `--columnsHaveTypes`, where you can specify the field type (in your case `string`) of the column being imported - try that one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223443/mongoimport-choosing-field-type