# Mongoose LIKE operator for numbers

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Mongoose allows a similar functionality using Regex for strings
But I did not find a single resource for how to use something similar for numbers

Say I have a number in my colection "88682265456" and when a user searches for "226" he get's that number and similar numbers, the way LIKE operator behaves in SQL databases.

I tried converting the field to a string using $where operator, but my atlas database tier does not support it.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222428/sql-like-operations-on-numbers-in-mongodb) helps you?

Comment: Yes. That answer makes sense. Thank you.